# How to remove duplicate values from an sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to know how to remove duplicate values from the output of an sql query.

This is the sql query:

```
$query = "SELECT useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs, 
energyconsumption.ElecEnergy, useraccount.Username as User
    FROM useraccount
    INNER JOIN tariff 
ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id
INNER JOIN energyconsumption
ON energyconsumption.User = useraccount.id
WHERE Date = CURRENT_DATE";
```

This is the output of that query:

```
{"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"2000"},  
{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"1900"}]}
```

As you can see, the query filters out data where the data matches todays date. We have 2 outputs for the same user. The value of the tariff name and username are the same,but the energy consumption value is different which is fine.

I want to achieve the following output:

```
= {"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"2000 +1900"}


= {"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"3900"}
```

Could someone point me to the direction in how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance to those who read the post and contributed!

Comment: Do you want to sum the values or you want them as `2000 +1900` ?

Comment: @Dekel Hi, yes I want the sum of the values

Comment: So the answer by @scaisEdge is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dekel   thanks   Your comment is loyal .. i upvote your answer .. (the meaning of the answer is practically the same)

Comment: well, not exactly the same because he wanted a sum (and not a string [like in his example]). you got my vote here as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a sum and a group by

```
$query = "SELECT useraccount.Username as Username, tariff.Name as TariffName, 
sum(energyconsumption.ElecEnergy) as ElecConsump
    FROM useraccount
    INNER JOIN tariff 
ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id
INNER JOIN energyconsumption
ON energyconsumption.User = useraccount.id
WHERE Date = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs";
```

(you have some difference between table column name alias and object attribute name  )

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! Could i ask you one last question. I tested the query, and im getting an error. This is the rest of the code after the query:  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  $r = array();
  if($result->num_rows){
  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($r, array( 'Username' => $row['Username'],
    'TariffName' => $row['tariffs'], 'ElecConsump' => $row['ElecEnergy']
    

    ));
    
    }
   
  } echo json_encode(array('results' => $r));
 
The error is in this line: if($result->num_rows)

Comment: @Dekel will do. Thanks!

Comment: @scaisEdge Done. Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @Mahbs   . if you have another question  post a proper new question ..  so all the SO user can help you

Comment: @scaisEdge Will do! Thank you once again!

Comment: @scaisEdge Regarding the query you posted, i understand that it groups the values, but would i end up having one entry in the result set? Because thats what i want, 1 entry in the result set, and that entry being:  {"results":[{"Username":"absc868","TariffName":"s1","ElecConsump":"3900"}

Comment: @Mahbs   then explain exactly your problem ... i have update the answer  adding the missing alias ..

Comment: Ok, so from the OP, we see that in the result set, we have 2 records. The username and tariff are the same right. However, the elec consumption for the same username is different. Want i want to do, is have a result set that has only one entry, meaning, in the username column you should only have 1 entry and that entry being "absc868", in the tariff column, you should have only one entry and that entry being "S1" and finally in the elec consumption column, you should only have one entry, and that entry being the addition of 2000 + 1900. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `group_concat` function:

```
$query = "SELECT useraccount.Username, tariff.Name as tariffs, 
GROUP_CONCAT(energyconsumption.ElecEnergy SEPARATOR ' +')
    FROM useraccount
    INNER JOIN tariff 
ON useraccount.tariffs = tariff.id
INNER JOIN energyconsumption
ON energyconsumption.User = useraccount.id
WHERE Date = CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY useraccount.Username, tariff.Name";
```